# Return a string of N spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to solve a problem from jshero.net. The problem is the following:

**Write a function spaces that takes a natural number n and returns a string of n spaces. spaces(1) should return ' '.**
I need to use a while loop to solve this challenge. The best solution I could come up with is:

```
function spaces(num) {
   let mySpaces = '';
  
   while(mySpaces === num) {
      mySpaces+= num}
   }
}
```

But it returns the following errors:

```
spaces(0) does not return '', but undefined.
Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You did not return `mySpaces`.

Comment: Yes, let your function `return` something. Right now it doesn't do this.

Comment: After that you can try to fix the logic of your loop.

Comment: I added `return mySpaces` and I got the following error:
** spaces(1) does not return ' ', but ''.

Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!**

Comment: you need to check `mySpaces.length`, so while mySpaces.length is less than the number you entered, keep adding spaces to the string

Comment: also `mySpaces+= num` is adding the number you entered into your function to the string `mySpaces (it's concatenating). You want to add spaces, not the number you entered

Comment: so the while loop needs to be `mySpaces.length<num`? And regarding the spaces that need to be added, that's the part that I am trying to figure out. How to make the program to understand that everytime I run the function with the number, I want that number to be represented in spaces as the result. I am thinking maybe `mySpaces[num]` but it's throwing me the same errors.

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne Yep `mySpaces.length<num` is correct! As you know `mySpaces += " "` will add 1 space to your `mySpaces` string. If you do `mySpaces += " "; mySpaces += " ";` then you'll add two spaces. So, if you repeat the line `mySpaces += " ";` _n_ times (ie: `num` times) then you will add _n_ spaces to your string. The code which repeats this is your while loop which you have already written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to return your output, and subtract from `num` each iteration:

```js
function spaces(num) {
  let mySpaces = '';

  while (num-- > 0)
    mySpaces += ' ';

  return mySpaces;
}

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(spaces(1)),
  '\n',
  JSON.stringify(spaces(5))
);
```

<strike>Ultimately, this seems to be the most elegant (and [performant](https://jsben.ch/9PK6H)) approach:</strike>

```js
const spaces = (n) => Array(n + 1).join(' ');
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(spaces(1)),
  '\n',
  JSON.stringify(spaces(5))
);
```

1.1M ops/s for `Array.join` vs. 86k for the `while` loop.

---

## EDIT

Totally blanked on `String.repeat`, thanks to Daniel for that. Pushing [2M ops/s](https://jsben.ch/eyw2o):

```js
const spaces = (n) => " ".repeat(n);

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(spaces(1)),
  '\n',
  JSON.stringify(spaces(5))
);
```

Comment: _"Ultimately, this seems to be the most elegant approach"_ - It's one of many...

Comment: Or, its possible use repeat. " ",repeat(n).

Comment: I tried the function that you mentioned and it showing up the following error:
<
spaces(1) does not return ' ', but ''.

Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!>

Comment: @DanielARF Totally forgot about `.repeat`, we'd need to do `n -1` for this case though. Now *that's* the most elegant (and performant) approach, big ups for leaving constructive feedback.

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne Oh, I misread your test example, I thought it wanted `spaces(1)` to map to an empty string for some reason. I updated, so the output should match up now.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine, but I feel like cheating or something for doing this :)). Thank you very much.

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne You'll find that looking stuff up on StackOverflow is a big part of the development process. I tried to show multiple ways to solve this, so that you can understand the process more intimately. Your main mistakes were that you forgot to **return a value from your function**, you were not **decrementing `num`** (you were adding to it), and your **conditional didn't make sense**: `while (mySpaces === num)` doesn't even execute once, because you're saying, "do X while `""` is equal to `10`.

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne If you want an exercise, delete all of the code and re-write it, from scratch. Just walk by it step by step: "Okay, it gets `num = 10`, and I need to loop 10 times, and add a space each loop." And just go from there. `num--` is a bit of a curveball because it's basically just using the `num` variable *as* the counter, but you don't need to do that. You could do `for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)` for instance. You can rewrite that directly as a `while` loop by just initializing `i` and then doing `while (i < num) { ...; i++; }`.

Comment: _"you were not decrementing num (**you were adding to it**)"_ - That (the bold part) is not true.

Comment: @Andreas You're right - he was not changing it at all, I misremembered what the `+=` operator was doing. Your vapid nitpicking is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just succeeded to resolve it with the litle help of other peoples answers here.

This is the code that solved :

```
function spaces(num){
   let s = '';
   while(s.length < num){
      s = ' '.repeat(num);
      return s;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    spaces=(n)=>{
     let a='';
      while(a.length<n){
       a= a+ ' ';
      }
     return a;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet worked for me; All tests passed!

```
function spaces(n){

 let a = '';
  while ( a.length<n ){
   a = a + ' ';}

 return a;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does this add to the already provided answers?

Comment: It is intended to be a solution for anyone who is working with the information available thus far in the jshero.net course on JavaScript @MoritzRingler

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct Code you need to put s.length<=num

```
    function spaces(num){
   let s = '';
   while(s.length <= num){
      s = ' '.repeat(num);
      return s;
   }
}
```